# How to extract the result of the snmpwalk and snmpgetnext,snmpget command in NET-SNMP using java?

Tags: java, string, java-8

When using snmpgetnext, snmpget command, I can get the total result only one row. The result is

`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0.1 = INTEGER: 1`

or

`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID`.

How can I get the real result like `1` or `No Such Instance currently exists at this OID`? Also, Why people have told me that using regex isn't good for this?

When using snmpwalk, it returns many rows. I want the `map<oid,reuslt>` like `<1.3.6.1.4.1.2352.2.4.1.4.1.3.18.1,36>`. I think the question may be the same with snmpgetnext.

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c testro 172.0.0.1 -On .1.3.6.1.4.1.2352.2.4.1.4.1.3
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2352.2.4.1.4.1.3.18.1 = Gauge32: 36
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2352.2.4.1.4.1.3.31.1 = Gauge32: 35
.1.3.6.1.4.1.2352.2.4.1.4.1.3.36.1 = Gauge32: 35
```

Comment: What prevents you from using a library like snmp4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex employing capturing groups to extract the bits where to an OID is associated a value or no value at all.

The first capturing group extracts the OID (just to use it later when printing the results). The second capturing group identifies either the `No Such Instance...` case or the corresponding value. Finally, the third and fourth capturing groups respectively grab the value associated and the no-such-instance string.

The presence of a fourth capturing group can be used to determine whether an OID has no instance associated or not. In case the fourth capturing group is null, then a value is associated and this can be read by referencing the third group.

Here is an implementation of the regex:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.([\d*.]+)\s+=\s+(.*?:(.*)|(.*))
```

Here is a link to test the regex:

https://regex101.com/r/y4FX6a/1

Here is a possible implementation:

```
String test = "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0.1 = INTEGER: 1\n" +
        "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID\n" +
        "SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (157736000) 18 days, 6:09:20.00";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.([\\d*.]+)\\s+=\\s+(.*?:(.*)|(.*))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

while (matcher.find()) {
    //Checking if the fourth capturing group exists (no value associated)
    if (matcher.group(4) != null) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " => " + matcher.group(4).trim());
    } else {
        //Otherwise if a match with pattern 'something:value' is found, then the third capturing group with only the value is returned
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " => " + matcher.group(3).trim());
    }
}
```

Here is a link to test the code above:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/tLd

##### Output

```
232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0.1 => 1
232.6.2.17.2.1.5.0 => No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 => (157736000) 18 days, 6:09:20.00
```

Comment: The result is not right.`1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (157736000) 18 days, 6:09:20.00`,get result Timeticks,but what I want is  `(157736000) 18 days, 6:09:20.00` or  `18 days, 6:09:20.00`

Comment: @flower I've updated my answer with your last sample containing `Timeticks`. If there are other cases which are not covered, please update your question with all the possible input syntax.

Comment: There are going to be much more complicated output patterns from NET-SNMP command line utilities, so the only feasible approach is to use a Java library like snmp4j to actually handle SNMP communication and touch the underlying data.